# Android how to open a popup window in an onclick function

Tags: android

In android I am trying to open a popup window to get some user input but the code fails in Activity.java on

```
    if (activity == null && children == null && fragments == null && loaders == null
            && mVoiceInteractor == null) {
        return null;
    }
```

Here are the xml files of the layout with the button to open the popup window and the xml of the popup window

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="15dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:text="Manually Enter Latitude and Longitude"
    android:background="#778899"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:paddingRight="25dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Latitude"
    android:background="#778899"
    />


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="30dip"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="Decimal\nDegrees"
        android:id="@+id/button_lat_dec_deg"
        android:onClick="enter_lat_dec_deg"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="OR"
        android:background="#778899"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="Degrees,\nMinutes and Seconds"
        android:id="@+id/button_lat_deg_min_sec"
        android:onClick="enter_lat_d_m_s"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:singleLine="false" />

</LinearLayout>

<View android:id="@+id/separator"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical ="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="25dip"
    android:paddingRight="25dip"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Longitude"
    android:background="#778899"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="30dip"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="Decimal\nDegrees"
        android:id="@+id/button_lon_dec_deg"
        android:onClick="enter_lon_dec_deg"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="OR"
        android:background="#778899"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="Degrees\nMinutes and Seconds"
        android:id="@+id/button_lon_deg_min_sec"
        android:onClick="enter_lon_d_m_s"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:singleLine="false" />

   </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>




<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/manually_entry" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Please enter the decimal Latitude"
    android:singleLine="true"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Negative is South"
    android:singleLine="true"
    />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
    android:id="@+id/enter_decimal_number" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and the code for the onclick function is

```
public void enter_lat_dec_deg(View v) {

    layout3 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.manually_enter_numbers, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.manually_entry));

    enter_manual_dec_deg = new PopupWindow(layout3 , 700,900,true);   // width, height
    layout3.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            enter_manual_dec_deg.showAtLocation(layout3, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 200);
        }
    });
    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enter_decimal_number);
    decimal_input = Float.valueOf(input.getText().toString());

    Toast.makeText(GPSTest.this, "this is the decimal input !!!" + decimal_input,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}
```

I have another popup window in the same app that works fine but the same code does not work here.

I am quite new to android programming have probably made a quite obvious mistake but I have done lots of googling and found nothing to fix the problem so any advice would be eagerly anticipated.
Please ask if you would like me to post more code.

The android studio event log has :

14:03:52 Session 'GPSTest': Launched on gigabyte-guru__gx-487d40a0
14:04:53 null
         java.nio.BufferOverflowException
         at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.put(HeapByteBuffer.java:206)
         at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.movePacket(JdwpPacket.java:235)
         at com.android.ddmlib.Debugger.sendAndConsume(Debugger.java:347)
         at com.android.ddmlib.Client.forwardPacketToDebugger(Client.java:709)
         at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:346)
         at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:265)

14:04:53 null
         java.nio.BufferOverflowException
         at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.put(HeapByteBuffer.java:206)
         at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.movePacket(JdwpPacket.java:235)
         at com.android.ddmlib.Debugger.sendAndConsume(Debugger.java:347)
         at com.android.ddmlib.Client.forwardPacketToDebugger(Client.java:709)
         at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:346)
         at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:265)

14:05:26 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
14:05:26 Gradle build finished in 679ms
14:48:36 null
         java.nio.BufferOverflowException
         at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.put(HeapByteBuffer.java:206)
         at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.movePacket(JdwpPacket.java:235)
         at com.android.ddmlib.Debugger.sendAndConsume(Debugger.java:347)
         at com.android.ddmlib.Client.forwardPacketToDebugger(Client.java:709)
         at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:346)
         at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:265)

and here is the logcat :

03-03 14:45:49.629 18174-18174/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-03 14:45:49.629 18174-18174/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4165cd58)
03-03 14:45:49.649 18174-18180/? D/dalvikvm: Debugger has detached; object registry had 3717 entries
03-03 14:45:49.649 18174-18174/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.example.david.gpstest, PID: 18174
                                                   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
                                                       at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18439)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5095)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                       at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 
                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18439) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5095) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602) 
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                       at com.example.david.gpstest.GPSTest.enter_lat_dec_deg(GPSTest.java:156)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                       at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818) 
                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 
                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18439) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5095) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602) 
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
03-03 14:45:52.259 18174-18174/com.example.david.gpstest I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 18174 SIG: 9

The code fails at the line :

```
        layout3 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.manually_enter_numbers, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.manually_entry));
```

Comment: Please post the logcat with the exception and make sure you provide the code where the exception occurs. What you have already posted in not enough.

Comment: I have edited the original question to include the Android studio event log and the logcat.

Answer (score 0):

David, Hello its yourself here. This is a design fault. Please redesign your app to use activities instead of popups. Have a nice day.